# How to decode JSON with codable in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, codable

i have a big problem with decoding JSON with Codable

I got the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(SpecieKeys(stringValue: "v", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key SpecieKeys(stringValue: \"v\", intValue: nil) (\"v\").", underlyingError: nil))

I spend many time but I don't understand why .. :-(

This is my json

```swift
let myJson = """
       [{"i":"4","p":"4","l":["Ail"],"ll":["Allium sativum L."]},
        {"i":"20.1","l":["Artichaut"],"ll":["Cynara cardunculus"]},
        {"i":"XX.3",
         "l":["Tomate cerise"],
         "ll":["Solanum humboldtii"],
         "v":[{"s":1,
               "i":"0",
               "l":"Orange Grape Tress",
               "c":"Orange",
               "h":992,
               "ss":12
              }]

        }]
    """
    let jsonDATA = myJson.data(using: .utf8)!
```

and my struct

```swift
struct Specie : Decodable {
var id : String?
var name : [String]?
var latinName : [String]?
var varieties : [Variety]?

// keys
enum SpecieKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "i"
    case name = "l"
    case latinName = "ll"
    case varieties = "v"
}

struct Variety : Decodable {
    var source : Int?
    var id : String?
    var color : String?
    var name : String?
    var photo : String?
    var harvest : Int?
    var semiShelter : Int?
    var semiOutside : Int?

    // keys
    enum VarietyKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "i"
        case source = "s"
        case color = "c"
        case photo = "p"
        case harvest = "h"
        case semiShelter = "ss"
        case semiOutside = "so"
        case name = "l"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let vValues = try decoder.container(keyedBy: VarietyKeys.self)
        id = try vValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        source = try vValues.decode(Int.self, forKey: .source)
        name = try vValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        color = try vValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .color)
        photo = try vValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .photo)
        harvest = try vValues.decode(Int.self, forKey: .harvest)
        semiShelter = try vValues.decode(Int.self, forKey: .semiShelter)
        semiOutside = try vValues.decode(Int.self, forKey: .semiOutside)
    }
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
{
    let sValues = try decoder.container(keyedBy: SpecieKeys.self)
    id = try sValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try sValues.decode(Array<String>.self, forKey: .name)
    latinName = try sValues.decode(Array<String>.self, forKey: .latinName)
    varieties = try sValues.decode(Array<Variety>.self, forKey: .varieties)
}
}
```

And the last code

```swift
var jsonResult = [Specie]()

jsonResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Specie>.self, from: jsonDATA)
```

Someone can help me about my mistake.

Comment: Don't use `try!`. Write a try/catch block and log the error you're getting.

Comment: You can also write `[Variety].self` for arrays, we don't often use generic syntax `Array<Variety>` for arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: with Try, the error is "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every optional value you have to use [decodeIfPresent(*:forKey)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2894339-decodeifpresent) instead of [decode(:forKey)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2921358-decode). `decode(_:forKey)` will fail your parsing when it finds a `nil` value (`"No value associated with key ..."`)

However, the easier solution would be to let the compiler generate your decoding initializers:

```
struct Specie : Decodable {
    var id : String?
    var name : [String]?
    var latinName : [String]?
    var varieties : [Variety]?

    // keys
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "i"
        case name = "l"
        case latinName = "ll"
        case varieties = "v"
    }

    struct Variety : Decodable {
        var source : Int?
        var id : String?
        var color : String?
        var name : String?
        var photo : String?
        var harvest : Int?
        var semiShelter : Int?
        var semiOutside : Int?

        // keys
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "i"
            case source = "s"
            case color = "c"
            case photo = "p"
            case harvest = "h"
            case semiShelter = "ss"
            case semiOutside = "so"
            case name = "l"
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing necessary is to rename your key enums to `CodingKeys` so that the compiler can recognize them.

Comment: I think you mean for every optional KEY you need decodeIfPresent. Optional values are handled by just marking them optional.

Comment: @smileBot True. However, I would always use `decodeIfPresent` since many JSON encoders will remove keys with `null` values and a sane decoder should handle both cases.

Comment: That's a smart point. Actually I wonder if you save a JSON encoded object to user defaults if it removes the nil keys from the object. I'll have to test this as I'm about to do just this in my project!

Comment: @smileBot Generated `Encodable` uses `encodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` for optional values and that does not encode `null`. You can enforce encoding `null` with custom implementation.

Comment: I'm actually talking about decoding in my response not encoding. But good to know the default encoder skips nils. That's not that surprising. If you want to encode a nil value you have to use NSNull.

Comment: @smileBot No, you don't. You can use `encode(optional, forKey: key)`. The generated encoder uses `encodeIfPresent` which excludes `null` values. If you write custom encoding and use `encode`, then `null` will be preserved. Definitely don't use `NSNull` in Swift :)